# How can I prevent Grails 3 from ever creating a session?

Tags: session, grails, spring-security

I have a Grails 3.1 app and use the spring security plugin, with with a custom stateless authentication provider. This all works, but I still get redirects to my login screen when there is no session, and a session created (with a session id cookie).

How can I instruct spring security to never use cookies, or alternatively, grails to never allow them to be created? I've seen a few answers around plain spring security but with the Grails spring security plugin, things appear to work differently.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security plugins work with filters, probably one of them is redirecting you to the login page. I don't know exactly how you customized your authentication, but based on [Spring Security REST Plugin](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/#_plugin_configuration), you should remove from the filter chain the ones that you don't need.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    //Stateless chain
    [
        pattern: '/api/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
    ],

    //Traditional chain
    [
        pattern: '/**',
        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you, with this approach, I have been able to avoid a session being required for authentication, i.e. with my token set and no session, I no longer get redirected back to the login page. However, something is still insisting on creating a session then I'm redirected to the login page, despite me having a custom LoginController and view. Any ideas what would do that?

Comment: Nope. But set the level of the spring security logs to debug, maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to set to *false*, at least, the following **Spring Security** properties in order to properly disable session creation.

*application.groovy*

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.scr.allowSessionCreation = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.scpf.forceEagerSessionCreation = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.allowSessionCreation = false
```

You have more information in the Grails Spring Security Plugin [documentation website](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/#miscProperties).